# comparando lista con variable- IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

soy nuevo en esto de la programacion y estoy probando un programa que he hecho para profundizar conceptos basicos sobre estos.

el programa es muy simple, quiero saber si hay en una lista coincide con el ID de la variable:

```
id=input("id: ")
L=[input("id:otro ")]
if id==L[1]:
    print(("okay"))
else:
    print("not")
```

el error que me genera es el siguiente:

```
id: 12345678z
id:otro 12345678z
```

## lo de arriba es lo que he introducido y luego me sale error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/TOSHIBA/prubas.py", line 3, in <module>
    if id==L[1]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Pasa que en python como la mayoría de lenguajes de programación, son **ceroindexados** lo que quiere decir que tu primer elemento no es el número `1` si no el `0`. Por lo que la validación correcta sería: `id == L[0]`

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta a tu pregunta es sencilla y bastaría con un comentario, pero creo que no está de más explicar brevemente las posibilidades de indexación para este lenguaje.

En el caso de `Python`, la indexación se puede realizar de dos formas: a través de índices positivos, cuyo índice inicial es `0`, o a través de íncides negativos, cuyo índice inicial es `-1`. Esto permite realizar recorridos tanto desde posiciones positivas como negativas, algo que puede ser útil en según qué situaciones.

Tomando como referencia una lista tal que así:

`list test=[1,2,3,4]`

Los valores correspondientes a cada posición, tomando como referencia índices positivos, serían:

```
test[0] -> 1
test[1] -> 2
test[2] -> 3
test[3] -> 4
```

En el caso de íncides negativos, el valor de cada posición sería:

```
test[-1] -> 4
test[-2] -> 3
test[-3] -> 2
test[-4] -> 1
```

En tu caso, el problema es simple. El error indica que estás accediendo a una posición fuera del índice, ya que `L` tiene un único valor declarado en la lista (`L[0]`). Por lo tanto, para realizar la comparación que intentas, lo correcto sería:

```
id=input("id: ")
L=[input("id:otro ")]
if id==L[0]:
    print(("okay"))
else:
    print("not")
```